# OpenMPI-bin error after update (K)Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, mpi, openmpi

I have just upgraded my Kubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04. Unfortunately there is an error that keeps showing up everytime I use apt upgrade or installing something with apt. The error is:

```
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/mpi corrupt: slave link same as main link /usr/bin/mpicc
```

It has been [reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openmpi/+bug/1874645) and yet has not been patched until the time I write this question.

After more than a month trying various ways to deal with this problem I finally found the solution as you can see below. I hope it is useful for you who met with the same problem.

Comment: Had this error also. Other errors that popped up with this one (for google as you have the perfect answer) were "E: Internal Error, No file name for openmpi-bin:amd64" and "/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: openmpi-bin is broken or not fully installed" and "dpkg: error processing package openmpi-bin"

Answer (score 82):

First remove the update-alternatives for openmpi:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/alternatives/mpi* /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/mpi*
```

Then install openmpi-bin again:

```
sudo apt install open-mpi
```

answer Y when asked for confirmation.

In Ubuntu 22.04 (or if the above line doesn't work) - try this instead:

```
sudo apt install openmpi-bin
```

Comment: sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/mpi; sudo apt install openmpi-bin

Comment: Resolved a similar issue for me upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04

Comment: Thank you for this - and ditto what @ScottMcC said above, removing the alternatives links resolved an error I was encountering going from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 as well.